# how to inject a jquery code to a HTML page dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add a javascript code , which i getting from the server to my view .

is this possible .

i am doing this

```
    jQuery(".city").change(function(){

        var address = jQuery('#business-address').val();
        var city = jQuery('.city').val();
        var state = jQuery('.state').val();
        var country = jQuery('.country').val();

        var address_string = address+","+city+","+state+","+country;

        jQuery.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: baseurl+"home/auth/create_google_map_from_address",
              data:{address:address_string},
              success: function(data,status){

                  var data_array = JSON.parse(data);                  

                  var latitude = data_array['map']['markers']['marker_0'].latitude;
                  var longitude = data_array['map']['markers']['marker_0'].longitude;
                  var map_js = data_array['map'].js;
                  var map_html = data_array['map'].html;
                  alert(latitude);

                  jQuery('#gmap_js').html(map_js);

              } 
         });
    });
```

i am getting a javasript code to variable `map_js`

i want to add this code to the html page ,

currently i am using `jQuery('#gmap_js').html(map_js);`

but it is not working , how to do this .

this is map_js

[image]

please help...........

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, make you use escape character back slash \ where you need as you will see in [the example code](http://jsfiddle.net/BRWg6/).

```
var map_js = '<script language="javascript" type="text\/javascript"> alert("Js");<\/script>'

jQuery('head').append(map_js);
```

​